# Can I Use MemcacheDB to Replace Memcached in django?

Tags: django, caching, memcached, memcachedb

I want to use MemcacheDB instead of Memcached because I don't have a lot of RAM for Memcached.

Will it work with django's cache framework?

Is there anything additional I would need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think this should just work. The whole idea of MemcacheDB is to give a BDB backend through existing and tested memcache client libraries. Django just sits on top of that.

Comment: It did work. MemcacheDB doesn't handle expirations so you have to do on your own.

Comment: It's funny that expiration is in the SET syntax, but it is ignored.